# Remove one of two Rows where first column is identical and second with different date

Tags: sql, oracle

Imagine i have such a table :

```
Nr          Date

2162416     14.02.2014 
2162416     11.08.2006 
2672007     13.04.2016 
2672007     27.11.2007 
3030211     31.01.2013 
3030211     25.04.2006 
3108243     11.04.2016 
3108243     24.08.2009 
3209248     05.04.2016 
3209248     08.06.2012 
3232333     11.04.2012 
3232333     23.12.2011 
3232440     08.04.2013 
3232440     23.01.2008
```

as you can see, the entries are pairs which only differ on value of date column. How can i delete one of them by comparing date. I want to remove the old ones.

There can be only two rows with same Nr

Comment: If there are 3 rows with same Nr, do you want to keep 1 or 2 rows?

Comment: there can be only two rows with same Nr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple way, use `EXISTS` to remove a row if another row with same Nr but later date exists:

```
delete from tablename t1
where exists (select 1 from tablename t2
              where t2.nr = t1.nr
                and t2.date > t1.date)
```

Alternatively:

```
delete from tablename
where (nr, date) not in (select nr, max(date) from tablename group by nr)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you always have pairs of rows, you can use:

```
delete your_table
where (nr, date) in (
                     select nr, min(date)
                     from your_table
                     group by nr
                    )
```

If you want to handle the case in which you only have one row, you can add a condition:

```
delete your_table
where (nr, date) in (
                     select nr, min(date)
                     from your_table
                     group by nr
                     having count(1) > 1
                    )
```

Comment: @jarlh: you're right, I was just editing to handle the single row

Answer (score 1):

An approach using a Common Table Expression (CTE):

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE (nr, date) IN
(
   WITH x AS 
   (
      SELECT nr, date, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY nr ORDER BY date DESC) AS n 
      FROM your_table
   )
   SELECT nr, date
   FROM x
   WHERE n > 2
);
```